# How can I count some stats fromm- file in C?

Tags: c, file

I need to wrote a C code which counts vowels, consonants, words, lines and total character count. I did some serching And I did this:

```
div{
    include <stdio.h>
    include <stdlib.h>

    char name[64];
    printf("Dosya ismi: ");
    fgets(name, 64, stdin);
    FILE *fp;
    int vowel=0,consonant=0,count=0,lines=0,words=0;
      char ch;

    fp = fopen ("name", "w+");
    if(name == NULL)
    {
    printf("Dosya acilamadi!\n");
    exit(-1);
    }
    fputs("Bu metin dosyasinda bazi istatistikleri gozlemleyecegiz", fp);
    fclose (fp); 
    fp = fopen ("name", "r");
    ch=fgetc(fp);
      while(ch!=EOF)
            {
                           count++;

                   if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')
                          {
                           lines++;
                          }

                   if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')
                       {  
                           words++;
                       }

                   if((ch=='a')||(ch=='A')||(ch=='e')||(ch=='E')||(ch=='i')||(ch=='I')||(ch=='o') || 
                   (ch=='O')||(ch=='u')||(ch=='U'))
                     {
                           vowel++;
                      }
                  else
                     {
                         consonant++;
                     }



                         ch=fgetc(fp);
            }
                         printf("\n Sesli harflerin sayisi = %d",vowel);
                         printf("\n Sessiz harflerin sayisi = %d",consonant);
                         printf("\n Toplam harf sayisi = %d",count);
                         printf("\n Kelime sayisi = %d",words);
                         printf("\n Cumle sayisi = %d",lines);

      fclose (fp); 
      exit(0);                    
      }
      }
```

I'm getting this wrong counts instead of proper counts:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i0Xm.png)

What is my mistake and how can I solve this? How can I get true counts from my file.

Answer (score 0):

some minor changes to make this compile:

```
 #include <stdio.h> //add #
 #include <stdlib.h> //add #
 int main() //what is div? use main
 { //add at row start
     char name[64];
     printf("Dosya ismi: ");
     fgets(name, 64, stdin);
     FILE *fp;
     int vowel=0,consonant=0,count=0,lines=0,words=0;
     char ch;

     fp = fopen ("name", "w+");
     if(fp== NULL)
     {
         printf("Dosya acilamadi!\n");
         exit(-1);
     }
     fputs("Bu metin dosyasinda bazi istatistikleri gozlemleyecegiz", fp);
     fclose (fp);
     fp = fopen ("name", "r");
     ch=fgetc(fp);
     while(ch!=EOF)
     {       
         count++;           

         if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')
         {                 
             lines++;       
         }                 

         if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')
         {              
             words++;       
         }              

         if((ch=='a')||(ch=='A')||(ch=='e')||(ch=='E')||(ch=='i')||(ch=='I')||(ch=='o') || 
                 (ch=='O')||(ch=='u')||(ch=='U'))
         {            
             vowel++;       
         }             
         else      
         {            
             consonant++; 
         }            



         ch=fgetc(fp);    
     }       
     printf("\n Sesli harflerin sayisi = %d",vowel);
     printf("\n Sessiz harflerin sayisi = %d",consonant);
     printf("\n Toplam harf sayisi = %d",count);
     printf("\n Kelime sayisi = %d",words);
     printf("\n Cumle sayisi = %d",lines);

     fclose (fp); 
     exit(0);  
 }     
 //remove }
```

Other than that, it works for me:

```
Dosya ismi: 333333ddsffbvbgfheee

 Sesli harflerin sayisi = 21
 Sessiz harflerin sayisi = 34
 Toplam harf sayisi = 55
 Kelime sayisi = 5
 Cumle sayisi = 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much man ! But there is a little problem here. Kelime sayisi means words and it says 5 but there are 6. And Cumle sayisi means lines and it says 0 but there is 1 actually. Other counts are correct though.

Comment: words and lines should start counting with 1 not zero, since ' ' or '\n' will give you the 2nd word/line

Comment: Thank you, you were so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code does not compile!, first because it does not define any functions. This makes it very difficult for us to reproduce the problem.  Suggest modifying the code to be a `main()` function.

regarding:

```
char ch;
```

this is being set by: `fgetc()`. Which returns an `int`, not a `char`. and (depending on the 'signness' of a character in your implementation) the value EOF might not be recognized. suggest changing that statement to:

```
int ch;
```

regarding:

```
if(name == NULL) 
{ 
    printf("Dosya acilamadi!\n");
```

1. The if() should be checking `fp`, not `name`.
2. Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`. When the
   error is from a C library function should also output to `stderr` the
   text reason the system thinks the error occurred. A simple/reliable
   way to do this is to call

   perror( "Dosya acilamadi!" );

OT: for ease of readability and understanding:

1. please consistently indent the code. Indent after every opening brace '{'. Unindent before every closing brace '}'. Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. Note: each person uses an editor where the width of a tab can be set to some value other than 8, So please do not use tabs for indenting.
2. please follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at
   most) one variable declaration per statement.

OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis' I.E. 64. 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest using a `#define` statement or a `enum` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name, then using that meaningful name throughout the code.

regarding:

```
fp = fopen ("name", "r");
```

Always check the returned value (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful

regarding:

```
fclose (fp); 
fp = fopen ("name", "r");
```

much better to call: `rewind( fp );` or `fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_SET );`

OT: in English, the letter `y` is (sometimes) also a vowel.  however, this is not implemented in the answer.

regarding:

```
fgets(name, 64, stdin);
```

The function: fgets() includes the trailing newline '\n' into the input buffer. Therefore, the code needs to remove that trailing newline. One good way to do it is:

```
name[ strcspn( name, "\n") ] = '\0';
```

regarding: `div{` This is NOT part of the C language, so should not be included in the posted code.

regarding expressions like:

```
|(ch=='u')||(ch=='U')
```

Much better to make use of the `toupper()` or `tolower()` functionality from the header file: `ctype.h`

The following proposed code implements the above corrections and produces the correct output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_BUF_LEN 64

int main( void )
{
    char name[ MAX_BUF_LEN ];

    printf( "Dosya ismi: " );
    if( ! fgets( name, MAX_BUF_LEN, stdin ) )
    {
        perror( "fgets failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // remove trailing newline, if any
    name[ strcspn( name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    int vowel     = 0;
    int consonant = 0;
    int count     = 0;
    int lines     = 1;
    int words     = 1;
    int ch;

    FILE *fp = fopen ( "name", "w+" );
    if( !fp )
    {
        perror( "Dosya acilamadi!" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    fputs( "Bu metin dosyasinda bazi istatistikleri gozlemleyecegiz", fp );
    fflush( fp );
    rewind( fp );

    while( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
    {
        count++;

        if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')
        {
            lines++;
        }

        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')
        {  
            words++;
        }

        // Note: the following fails to handle punctuation
        if( ch == toupper('a')
          ||ch == toupper('e')
          ||ch == toupper('i')
          ||ch == toupper('o') 
          ||ch == toupper('u') )
        {
            vowel++;
        }

        else
        {
            consonant++;
        }
    }
    fclose (fp);

    printf( "\n Sesli harflerin sayisi = %d", vowel );
    printf( "\n Sessiz harflerin sayisi = %d", consonant );
    printf( "\n Toplam harf sayisi = %d", count );
    printf( "\n Kelime sayisi = %d", words );
    printf( "\n Cumle sayisi = %d", lines );

    return(0);                  
}
```

Note: the production of a 'state machine' for the counting of words and lines would be much better, but that is not implemented in this answer.